# Android Studio 2020.3 Canary 4 Cannot Sync Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I wanted to experiment with Jetpack Compose recently and so I started following the instructions on the Android Dev site and downloaded the latest Canary version of Android Studio. However, this version of Android Studio refuses to sync Grade properly.

The specific error messages is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
                initialization script 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle': 4: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
                @ line 4, column 1.
                import org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
                ^
                1 error
                (13 s 891 ms)
```

I've seen a few posts and tried those solutions (deleting the .gradle folder, invalidating cache and restarting, reinstalling Android Studio, Android SDK, JDK, etc.) but to no avail. Anyone have any idea as to what would be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall your android studio on you s